# Using @me.com email when @icloud.com is also available

Tags: mail.app

On iCloud Mail I can see that I have two email adresses:

1. myname@me.com
2. myname@icloud.com

I would like to use the @me.com as my primary email address. However, on Apple Mail (on macOS and iOS), it only lists my @icloud.com email as an option when composing mails.

How do I change that behaviour to @me.com?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Mail, Preferences and click on the account tab. You should iCloud in the column on the left. Click on that and a panel appears with your email adress. See image below.

[image]

Now if you click on the blue arrow at the end of your email address you should be able to choose the one you want.

Comment: Only my icloud.com account shows up in that dropdown-menu.